# How to get message contract to send soap action in body and not header

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, soap

When i use the "/messageContract" in my svcutil command, my soap message sends the action or operation in the header of the soap envelope and not the body. The remote endpoint is a vendor's Java based service which i have no control over.

I need the action to to be sent in the body but still use "/messageContract".

**Does anyone know how to achieve this?**

SOAP envelope **WITH** "/messageContract"

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">GetCapabilities</Action>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"></s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

SOAP envelope **WITHOUT** "/messageContract"

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header></s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<GetCapabilities xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2"></GetCapabilities>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

my svcutil command:

```
svcutil /target:code http://localhost/sarpilot/xml/mywisdl.wsdl /messageContract /out:WebService.cs /config:WebService.config
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are truly sure your target (Java-based) web service requires a Microsoft-based namespace element in the SOAP body instead of the SOAP header? That seems bogus to me.

```
<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">GetCapabilities</Action>
```

Most web services only need the [Action in the HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383531), not as part of the SOAP body:

```
POST /StockQuote HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length: nnnn
SOAPAction: "http://electrocommerce.org/abc#MyMessage"

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope...
```

Can you provide a raw, working SOAP request (including HTTP headers) for comparison? You can test it out independent from .NET by using this little web-page based client: [Simplest SOAP example using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript). I assume from your other posting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460107/soap-xml-response-received-but-not-populating-response-object) which shows a "working" request that you really don't need the Microsoft `Action` element in your SOAP body.

Comment: Thanks for your post. The target web service does NOT require a Microsoft-based namespace element. It does however require the operation to be in the BODY of the SOAP Request and not in the Header. That is why i need the firs to look more like the second soap request. Second soap request (SOAP envelope WITHOUT "/messageContract") is a RAW example of a working SOAP request. I tested it out independent of .NET using SOAPUI.

Comment: Right, so you don't need the `Action` element in the body at all, just the actual *operation* element in the body. Where's the problem, then?

Comment: I would still like to use "/messageContract" because for some (weird) reason i thought it might make my code work. I GUESS THE REAL problem is still http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460107/soap-xml-response-received-but-not-populating-response-object Should i close this post? It is pretty redonkulous now that you point it out. My real problem is the above link.

Comment: Tell you what, i'll leave this open, but help me figure out why objects are not populating (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460107/soap-xml-response-received-but-not-populating-response-object) and i'll give you BOTH answers :)